# ¿¿Mi constructor está mal?

Tags: java

necesito ayuda sobre mi código. Lo que pasa es que en mi clase **Prueba** en el método principal, cree un objeto "op" de clase **Operaciones** para que pudiera instanciar las clases y así usar los métodos de la clase **Operaciones**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {

   //private int dec1, int frac1;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Operaciones op = new Operaciones();
        Prueba teemo = new Prueba();
        teemo.menu();
        //op.decABinario( 10, 0 );  //Está si funciona, pero yo quiero que ingrese datos
        //op.Print();

    }
```

Me marca un error sobre el constructor Operaciones, pero ya lo cree en la clase **Operaciones**. Así que no se como solucionarlo.

```
public class Operaciones {
   private int dec1, frac1;
    private int frac;

   public Operaciones(int dec, int frac){
       this.dec1 = dec;
       this.frac1 = frac;
    }
```

Y por otra parte, quisiera saber como acceder a un método de la clase **Operaciones** desde la clase **Prueba**, digamos acceder al siguiente método para convertir números a binarios.

```
Numero n1 = new Numero();
    Numero n2 = new Numero();


    public void decABinario(int dec1, int frac1){
        if(dec1 > 0){
            StringBuffer enteroBtmp = new StringBuffer();
            n1.setEntDec(dec1);
```

(EDITADO)
Anexo capturas de las clases.
[image: Clase Operaciones]

[image: Clase Prueba[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0j1I.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun entiendo por los anexos, el lugar donde se encuentra la funcion **void menu() {...}** debe ser la carpeta `package calculadora;` al igual que la clase *Operaciones*

Si este es el caso, solo tienes que agregar `import calculadora.Operaciones;` en la parte superior, quedando tu codigo de la siguiente manera:

```js
package calculadora;
import calculadora.Operaciones;

public class XXXXX {

    // otros fragmentos de codigo...
    // ...
    // ...

    public void menu() {
        // ...
        // El constructor de la clase Operaciones
        // recibe 2 parametros (dec y frac)
        // por lo tanto al instanciarla con la
        // palabra 'new' debes pasar 2 parametros
        // como en el caso de abajo...
        Operaciones op = new Operaciones(0,0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow!!!, sí funcionó, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar el `import` de tu Clase Operaciones, si estas usando NetBeans como IDE puedes importar la clase facilmente presionando (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero me dice "Nothing to fix in import statements" :(

Comment: quizas el problema con respecto al import pueda deberse a un error de sintaxis podrias enviar la estructura de tus package y de la clase Prueba completa?

Comment: package calculadora;

public class Prueba {
  public static void main(String[] args){
        Prueba teemo = new Prueba();
        teemo.menu();   
    }
    
    public void menu(){
        int dec = entrada.nextInt();
        int frac = entrada.nextInt();
        Operaciones op = new Operaciones(); //Mi instancia
        op.decABinario(dec, frac); //Deberían llegar los datos ingresados a esté método
        op.Print();

Comment: No me permite enviar todo. Cómo te lo puedo enviar??

Comment: puedes anexar imagenes editando la pregunta principal?

Comment: Listo, ya edite mi publicación.